# access restrictions in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have 2 projects(say A and B) inside Rational Software Architect(its similar to eclipse).Now one project A is internally using other B .Now i am getting following errors

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Access restriction: The type Constants is not accessible due to restriction on required project B
    - Access restriction: The field xyz from the type Constants is not accessible due to restriction on required 
     project B
    - Access restriction: The type String is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\XYZ\AB
     \runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\lib\vm.jar
```

Now how can  i suppress these ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/access_rules.htm